# How to apply conditional return statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have this html input:

```
Rows: <input type="text" class="rows" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"><br>
```

and this javascript function to validate only numbers

```
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

but i want to work with micro-branching to do something like this:

```
function isNumber(evt){
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode; 
  (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && return false;
  return true;
}
```

the thing is that the last 2 lines didnt work.

Comment: what you trying to do in second last line ? it seems if is missing but again what is that && return false ..is it typo ?

Comment: 1. the second sample is ugly. 2. `return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));` 3. The `&&` operand must be an expression not a statement

Comment: @zerkms it works, thanks!

Comment: Not what you're asking, but you know the code shown doesn't actually stop the user entering non-numeric data into that input, right? (Because the keyboard isn't the only option for editing...)

Comment: @nnnnnn i didnt think about it but you are right, im doing this:
`window.onload = function() {
  var myInput = document.querySelector('.rows');
  myInput.onpaste = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}`

Comment: The user can also drag'n'drop with the mouse. But in any case you *are* validating all input server-side too, right? (Assuming this is data that gets sent to the server...)

Comment: @nnnnnn noup, im doing conway algorithm, im learning... btw thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` is a statement rather than an expression, and thus cannot be used as argument to a logical operator.

In your case however, the last two lines can be rewritten into a single `return` statement, by simply inverting the condition to the `if` clause:

```
return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
```

Or, as [zerkms notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602033/isnumber-function-without-if-statement-in-javascript/38602071#comment64591796_38602071), you can lose the `!` by flipping the operators (`&&` <=> `||` and `<` <=> `>=`), which, in my humble opinion, increases readability:

```
return charCode <= 31 || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57);
```

Comment: Btw, `return charCode <= 31 || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57);`

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it looks like you are looking for conditional check and return :

```
function isNumber(evt){
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode; 
  return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
}
```